# How save my SQLITE DB to Google Drive?

Tags: android, sqlite, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

I have tried 6+ Example Project but all the project give this same response:

```
GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{e00b1fb: android.os.BinderProxy@e266432}, message=null}
```

Where google drive api don't require any client id or access token. I also tried google official projects:
https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart
https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos
&
https://www.numetriclabz.com/integrate-google-drive-in-android-tutorial/

All of this Just show Google Sign In Screen and after click on account it's show same screen again and again. Now I can't understand the problem. Please give me a solution or way to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Why did you tag with MySQL backup?  MySQL is a very different database than SQLite.

Comment: That was a mistake. I just removed it. Thanks @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I solved this problem by following this steps:

1. Generate SHA1 KEY of my debug.keystore or keystore of app by this Comment on CMD

   keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore /Users/..your_path../.android/debug.keystore -list -v
2. create the project in: https://developers.google.com/mobile/add
3. Enable the Drive API from: https://console.developers.google.com 
   And Create API key by SHA1 key & package name from Credentials tab.

Thats all :)